# How to find the number of group of consecutive 1 in each column of a 3d numpy array

Tags: python

For example, I have this:

```
 [[[1 0 1 0 1 0]
   [1 1 0 0 1 0]
   [0 1 1 0 1 0]
   [0 0 0 0 1 0]
   [1 0 1 0 1 0]
   [1 0 0 0 0 0]]

     [[1 0 1 0 1 0]
      [1 1 0 0 1 0]
      [0 1 1 1 1 0]
      [0 0 0 1 0 0]
      [1 0 1 1 1 0]
      [1 1 0 0 1 0]]]
```

and I'd like to have:

```
 [[[2 1 3 0 1 0]        
   [[2 2 3 1 2 0]]
```

Of course this is a reduction, my numpy array shape is (124,7650,18).
I know there is a simple method but I'm not able to find it out.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more the expected output ? not sure to understand how you found these values

Comment: He wants to know how many times do 1's appear in a column, as a group of consecutive 1's or on their own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `np.diff` to take the difference between the previous value on a given axis:

```
import numpy as np
np.diff(x, axis = 1)
array([[[ 0,  1, -1,  0,  0,  0],
        [-1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0, -1, -1,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0]],

       [[ 0,  1, -1,  0,  0,  0],
        [-1,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0],
        [ 0, -1, -1,  0, -1,  0],
        [ 1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0],
        [ 0,  1, -1, -1,  0,  0]]])
```

Then we want to count each time there was a 'switch' to one: so the diff is 1.

```
np.sum(np.diff(x, axis = 1) == 1, axis = 1)
array([[1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0]])
```

but, doing this we miss those columns that started with 1, so we can add them back on, giving you your answer:

```
np.sum(np.diff(x, axis = 1) == 1, axis = 1) + x[:,0,:]
array([[2, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0],
       [2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0]])
```